# Magento: can't set the default value of custom order attribute using installation script

Tags: magento, attributes, installation, default-value

I've added custom attribute to orders using *mysql4-install-1.0.0.php* in my module:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_status',  array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'My Status',
    'note'          => '',
    'default'       => "my_default_value",
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,
    'searchable'    => false,
    'filterable'    => false,
    'comparable'    => false,
    'unique'        => false
));
```

It works - when I look at **sales_flat_order** table, I see new varchar field *custom_status* in the table. But the default value is NULL instead of `"my_default_value"` as expected there. Any ideas, why?

PS. Installation script is really executed, I reset all to initial state each time.

UPD. *config.xml*

```
<resources>
        <mymodule_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Company_Mymodule</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mymodule_setup>
 ***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento Sales module has pseudo emulation of old EAV functionality. It takes only type property from your array to create a column in the database. Also it uses "grid" property for determining is it required to make the same column in grid representation table.

BTW, previous sales module that was based on EAV, was not using default, label, required and other properties as well. If you want to set a default value for this attribute you need create an observer for order before save event and set this data in it if field is empty.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Seems I've gotten that piece of code from something related to products, not to orders.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have it like this in your config.xml:

```
        <resources>
            <customattr_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Yourcompany_ModuleName</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customattr_setup>
        </resources>
```

The  `<class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>` is extremely important!

Then in the install script mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'order', 
    'customattr', 
    array(
        'type' => 'float', // or whatever you want here...
        'grid' => false
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I have such structure - please look at the updated text if my question. The only thing that I don't sure: really `<customattrname>_setup`, not `<modulealias>_setup` there?

Comment: @silex: Its ok if you use modulealias_setup , but make sure that the folder inside the sql folder is also called exactly the same. AFAIK you can even call it strangecatlolwut_setup as long as the folder inside the sql folder of your modules is called exactly the same.